# Python 2.7: How do I read single keypress in Linux (Including special characters)?

Tags: linux, python-2.7, keyboard-events

I have seen a lot of questions asked about how to read single keypress in python. For Windows, the answers say to use the msvcrt module, which works. But for Linux, they use something like this:

```
import termios, fcntl, sys, os
def kbhit():
    fd = sys.stdin.fileno()
    oldterm = termios.tcgetattr(fd)
    newattr = termios.tcgetattr(fd)
    newattr[3] = newattr[3] & ~termios.ICANON & ~termios.ECHO
    termios.tcsetattr(fd, termios.TCSANOW, newattr)
    oldflags = fcntl.fcntl(fd, fcntl.F_GETFL)
    fcntl.fcntl(fd, fcntl.F_SETFL, oldflags | os.O_NONBLOCK)
    try:
        while True:
            try:
                c = sys.stdin.read(1)
                return True
            except IOError:
                return False
    finally:
        termios.tcsetattr(fd, termios.TCSAFLUSH, oldterm)
        fcntl.fcntl(fd, fcntl.F_SETFL, oldflags)
```

or this:

```
def __init__(self):
    import tty, sys

def __call__(self):
    import sys, tty, termios
    fd = sys.stdin.fileno()
    old_settings = termios.tcgetattr(fd)
    try:
        tty.setraw(sys.stdin.fileno())
        ch = sys.stdin.read(1)
    finally:
        termios.tcsetattr(fd, termios.TCSADRAIN, old_settings)
    return ch
getch = _Getch()
```

The problem with those two is that they don't read special characters like cntrl-C (^C) or Arrow Keys. Is there a Linux way to read single keypress *including* special characters like arrow keys?

Answer (score 0):

Check this piece of code:

```
def AllKeys(NormalInput=1):
   """ Detect Key Input """

   import termios, sys, tty

   fd = sys.stdin.fileno()
   old_settings = termios.tcgetattr(fd)

   tty.setraw(fd)
   tty.setcbreak(fd) # Control + C 

   try:
      #while True:
      ch = sys.stdin.read(NormalInput)

      if ch == '\x1b':
         ch = ch.lstrip(' ')
         ch += sys.stdin.read(2)

   finally:
      termios.tcsetattr(fd, termios.TCSADRAIN, old_settings)
   return ch
```

In my case it works as intended! It detect ctrl + 'char'

Just check this simple example of UDP client:

```
import socket

sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)

while True:

    try:

       InKey = AllKeys()

       print InKey

       if InKey == "\x03":
          raise KeyboardInterrupt

       elif InKey == '~':
          break

       else:  
          sock.sendto(InKey, (UDP_IP, UDP_PORT))

    except KeyboardInterrupt:
       break

sock.shutdown()
sock.close()
```

You can expand this easily with a server that process the characters received for virtual keyboard input with **Uinput** (Virtual HID Device). Then secure it with port control using **Iptables** rules. Add ssh tunneling for security. Otherwise you'll see plain data traffic in an **ARP Cache Poisoning** (MITM) testing.